# Avoids "to speak", or "speaking", to me?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

> Another baffling change/that I notice in him now-a-days/is that he avoids **to speak** to me.

In this sentence the error is said to be "to speak" is wrong and "speaking" will be used. I am not sure with which grammatical rule speaking should come.

Answer (score 2):

"to avoid" is always followed by a gerund (to avoid doing) and not by a to-infinitive. There is no telling why that is so, you simply have to learn it.Grammars deal with this problem in the chapter Infinitive or Gerund.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/avoid?q=avoid

http://www.really-learn-english.com/verbs-followed-only-by-gerunds.html