# "I'm avoiding traveling" or "I'm avoiding to travel"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to use two present continuous verb successively?

For example

> I'm avoiding traveling

Or it should be

> I'm avoiding to travel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoids "to speak", or "speaking", to me?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/avoids-to-speak-or-speaking-to-me)

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the link. I think Colin Fine has given a better answer than the one under that post so I am duplicating that post to this post instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one "present continuous" there, because there is only one tensed verb.

The second *-ing* word is a participle.

It happens that *avoid* takes a participial clause, not an infinitive one:

> I avoided seeing him.

not

> *I avoided to see him.

(There is no logic or rule that tells you this: it is a property of *avoid* that has to be learnt.)

So, since *avoid* takes an *-ing* clause, your example is perfectly normal:

> I'm avoiding travelling.
> (I use British spelling)

not

> *I'm avoiding to travel